# php resume file import

Tags: php, mysql

i have a client requirement with resume-able file import.i will tell the use case file imported is csv that corresponds to 3 mysql-table datas. during upload if any kind of warnings occure like name too long,description too long  it should stop execution and show the warning to client.client have 2 options ignore and re upload if he ignores then file upload will resume from the point where error happens and other option is simple just re upload the file.how should i continue the script execution after showing error msg ? how should i track no of csv lines get completed?

now lets explain my plan. i an using jquery ajax in first place.after saving each line of code save the no of lines executed in a session variable.if the user ignore the warning. then i will reupload csv and wait until the line no matches the one in session variable.is this the elegant way of doing things? reason why i put this question is each time user ignore the error msg according to my logic he/she needs to wait until the line stored in session reached. pls explain with an example if their is a better solution to this problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: You gave the solution yourself: you need to keep track of your progress in the import file so that you can easily skip the pat before. Wither you do that on the client side, or, more elegant, you import the csv into a temporary file and then process the entries of that one by one using the values for the final insert statement. That way you can use the database to store meta data. If required later you can implement more fancy features like uploading of several import files and processing them later on demand or in chunks.

Comment: thanks for your quick replay.what i understand is upload csv into a folder and read from there.what i was not clear is where do i keep  track of  progress from the import file ? where do i store the information regarding no of lines executed?

Comment: still wondering why i got a down vote for my question. is their any problem with quality of question ? so i will try to improve next time . pls let me know

Comment: Certainly you can also keep the CSV files in a server side folder, sure. Still you want to keep track of the import job in a database table, since it is easiest. Alternatively, if you want to keep that separate, you can use a simple file based sqlite database maybe.

Comment: Not sure about the down vote, but your question certainly is very broad, asking for general strategy which is not the point of SO. This place offers help for _specific_ issues with your existing implementation...

Answer (score 0):

#### A possible workflow

1. Analyze each line of the CSV file and load it into an empty table specially created for this purpose. The table should have the columns to store only the columns you import from the CSV file. It can also contain additional columns to store data that is computed during the import; f.e. if the processing and validation of the input data requires lookups
   into the data that already exists in the database, the values found should be also stored in the import table to avoid running the same queries again.
2. Ignore the lines from the CSV file that cannot be imported but keep track of their information (content, failure reason etc). You'll need the info to display it to the user.
3. If there are no errors in the CSV file then move the (validated) data from the special table into the destination tables and call it a success.
4. If there are errors show them to the user.

   - If the user decides to reload the CSV then start over with step 1.
   - If the user decides to ignore the errors then resume with step 3.

#### Advantages

- There is no need to upload the CSV file again.
- There is no need to keep track of the progress.

#### Disadvantages

- A lot of work is done then discard if the file is large, the error is at the beginning of CSV file and the user decides to upload it again. This can be improved in the algorithm by using an extra database table that contains the raw lines of the CSV file and an extra step (step 0): load the CSV file into it then use this table instead of the CSV file as input data for step 1. When a line is valid remove it from the CSV table; when a line is not valid then skip to step 4. When the user decides to ignore the error then resume with step 1.